# How to resize a gif without deforming and remove the blank white region when it's cropped?

Tags: command-line, convert, imagemagick, image-processing, gif

The below gif's dimensions are 600*800. Height is 800 pixels, so there's a lot of blank space at the bottom I want to remove.

[image: source gif: old.gif]

This was saved as `old.gif`:

```
file old.gif 
old.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 600 x 800
```

Resized with convert command:

```
convert old.gif -coalesce temp.gif
convert -size 600x800 temp.gif -resize 600x400! new.gif
```

`！` means ignore aspect ratio, do not keep aspect ratio unchanged.
Here's the result:

[image: squashed gif]

The new file `new.gif` is deformed.

How can I resize the gif without deforming it?

My try with `-crop` argument.

```
convert old.gif -crop 600x400+0+0 new.gif
```

[image: cropped gif with whitespace]

How to remove the blank region in new.gif?

The blank white region is obvious in firefox.
`convert old.gif -crop 600x400+0+0 new.gif` can't remove the blank white region in `new.gif`.

[image: gif in browser]

Using the `repage` argument will remove the blank white region, but it makes the gif more blurred.

```
convert old.gif -crop 600x400+0+0 -trim  +repage  new.gif
```

[image: blurry gif]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `!` after the resolution given to `-crop`:

```
convert old.gif -crop 600x400+0+0\! new.gif
```

[image]

From [the imagemagick docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_viewport):

> From ImageMagick version 6.2.4-5, you can add a new special flag to
>   the "`-crop`" argument. This flag '`!`' will tell crop to adjust the
>   Virtual Canvas information of the returned image so that it is
>   relative to the area cropped.
>
> ...
>
> Notice how the canvas size of the image returned now matches the area
>   in which the image was cropped.